# pandas concat() does not join on same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes which I am trying to concatenate. I made sure they have the same amount of columns and that the data types match.

However, when calling `pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)` I get a dataframe back with 24 columns and lots of `NaN` values. I expect [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to just place the second dataframe 'underneath' the first one (so the default; `axis=0`).

What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 798810 entries, 0 to 798809
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------  --------------   -----  
 0   0       798810 non-null  Int64  
 1   1       798810 non-null  float64
 2   2       798810 non-null  float64
 3   3       798810 non-null  float64
 4   4       798810 non-null  float64
 5   5       798810 non-null  float64
 6   6       798810 non-null  Int64  
 7   7       798810 non-null  float64
 8   8       798810 non-null  Int64  
 9   9       798810 non-null  float64
 10  10      798810 non-null  float64
 11  11      798810 non-null  float64
dtypes: Int64(3), float64(9)
memory usage: 75.4 MB
```

```
>>> df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 500 entries, 0 to 499
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   0       500 non-null    Int64  
 1   1       500 non-null    float64
 2   2       500 non-null    float64
 3   3       500 non-null    float64
 4   4       500 non-null    float64
 5   5       500 non-null    float64
 6   6       500 non-null    Int64  
 7   7       500 non-null    float64
 8   8       500 non-null    Int64  
 9   9       500 non-null    float64
 10  10      500 non-null    float64
 11  11      500 non-null    float64
dtypes: Int64(3), float64(9)
memory usage: 48.5 KB
```

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).shape
(799310, 24)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think columns names in one Dataframe are not numeric, but strings, so you can try:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int)
df2.columns = df2.columns.astype(int)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns=int), df2.rename(columns=int)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You are right; `df1.columns` returns `Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'], dtype='object')` versus `df2.columns`: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1)`. Casting the objects to integers fixes it. Confusing since this is not shown in `.info()`.